# Iniciando em Python Django

Tags: python, django

Sou programador web trabalho com o  ZendPhp OS linux Ubuntu e resolvi migrar para python. Tenho algumas duvidas. 
Python é uma linguagem interpretada! qual servidor terei que instalar para que tudo funcione perfeitamente, parece que o python já vem com seu servidor este já é indicado para o trabalho final?

procurando sobre a linguagem vi que ela tem um admin pré definido que não me agradou muito, eu consigo fazer meu layout totalmente diferente da ideia do django?

Ex..
primeira tela

- menus e home com a logo da empresa.
- Navegando no meu e escolhendo uma opção (Cadastro de produtos)
- o sistema manda o usuário para a listagem de produtos
- na listagem vai ter uma tabela contendo os registros e na mesma linha
  os icones que seria as ações (ver, alterar, deletar).

como é feito o banco de dados, fiquei meio perdido nessa parte. Estou acostumando a modelar meu banco postgres  e só depois ir para a parte do sistema fazendo o crud, porem todos os exemplos que encontrei foi com o próprio django criando o banco baseando em minhas classes.

Obs: não fiz nada na linguagem e nem a conheço direito por tanto sou 100% leigo no assunto.

Comment: aqui tem exemplos de paginas em django, talvez ajuda. https://github.com/brumazzi/DJango-Exemples

Comment: As perguntas são pertinentes, mas seria melhor separá-las em perguntas distintas, da forma como está ela está muito ampla (cada resposta teria que abordar cada item separadamente). Mas resumindo: 1) PHP também é interpretada, o que isso tem a ver? 2) O python costuma vir pré-instalado nos SOs Linux, mas um webserver você tem que escolher (e instalar) sozinho, o Django não é parte integrante do Python, é uma opção entre muitas; 3) Como a resposta do jsbueno fala, você usa o admin se quiser, não usa se não quiser, o "normal" é que o usuário final não toque nunca no admin (por segurança); 4)...

Comment: 4) o ORM do Django possui dois modos, o "gerenciado" (*managed*) e o "não gerenciado". No primeiro, você cria seus modelos usando código Python e a framework gera todo o SQL pra você. No segundo, o banco é criado por você próprio da maneira que achar melhor, e o ORM só **mapeia** cada tabela a um modelo e cada coluna da tabela com um campo do modelo. Nesse segundo caso, as ferramentas de migração de esquema não agem no banco, a estrutura é fixa e é você quem fica responsável por evolui-la (e garantir que o modelo de dados esteja consistente com a estrutura de tabela sendo usada).

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta não está inteiramente on-topic - mas vamos lá:

> Sou programador web trabalho com o ZendPhp OS linux Ubuntu e resolvi
>   migrar para python. Tenho algumas duvidas. Python é uma linguagem
>   interpretada! 
>   " Meio verdade" é muito fácil dizer que Python é uma linguagem interpretada - e as pessoas atribuem uma série de características falsamente por conta disso.
>   Python é uma linguagem dinâmica, fortemente tipada, e compilada para ByteCode - esse ByteCode é interpretado numa máquina virtual - essas características são iguais por exemplo, no Java, que é uma linguagem que as pessoas não associam a ser "interpretada".
>
> qual servidor terei que instalar para que tudo funcione
>   perfeitamente, parece que o python já vem com seu servidor este já é
>   indicado para o trabalho final?
>   O servidor Web que "encara" a internet, é, na maior parte das vezes um servidor HTTP d e propósito geral consolidado - como o Apache o Nginx. Esses servidores fazem a ponte para a aplicação Python. Dependendo do conjunto de tecnologias que você optar dentro do Python, é possível expor um servidor Python diretamente na Internet (Tornado, API-Hour, uWSGI, etc...) - mas isso não é relevante para o começo do trabalho.
>
> procurando sobre a linguagem vi que ela tem um admin pré definido que
>   não me agradou muito, eu consigo fazer meu layout totalmente diferente
>   da ideia do django?

o Admin do Django é uma ferramenta à mais, que permite que a aplicação funcione com um conjunto de telas CRUD (criação, edilção, deleção de elementos) assim que você defina seus modelos. Nenhuma aplicação é obrigada a a usar as telas do Django-admin.
Se ele cobrir toda  a funcionalidade que você precisa, sim, é possivel colocar temas diferentes nele, para ficar com outra aparência - mas a maioria das aplicações e sites definem visuaçlizações distintas, feitas de forma completamente separada do django-admin.

> Ex.. primeira tela
>
> menus e home com a logo da empresa. Navegando no meu e escolhendo uma
>   opção (Cadastro de produtos) o sistema manda o usuário para a listagem
>   de produtos na listagem vai ter uma tabela contendo os registros e na
>   mesma linha os icones que seria as ações (ver, alterar, deletar).

A apresentação, e quais views seu sistema terá, você define a medida que for desenvolvendo. Se você seguir um tutorial comum de django, terá demonstrações de como desenvolver as views.

> Como é feito o banco de dados, fiquei meio perdido nessa parte. Estou
>   acostumando a modelar meu banco postgres e só depois ir para a parte
>   do sistema fazendo o crud, porem todos os exemplos que encontrei foi
>   com o próprio django criando o banco baseando em minhas classes.

o Django possui um ORM (Adaptador Objeto-Relacional) próprio, bem simples  de usar, e que, na maior parte dos casos, prescinde que você crie coisas diretamente no banco. VOcê pode modelar todos os seus modelos de dados diretamente com classes de Python, que herdem da classe Model definida no Django. O conjunto de ferramentas que acompanha esse framework especificamente gera o SQL para você. Se for o caso, você pode opcionalmente editar esse SQL gerado antes dele ser executado automaticamente no banco (por exemplo, para adicionar opções na criação de tabelas que possam levar a uma maior performance para sua aplicação). Em geral esse passo não é necessário.

O Django é *um* dos frameworks web disponíveis para Python, e um dos mais completos - seguindo um bom tutorial, ele pode sim servir para você começar e se tornar proeficiente de forma mais ou menos rápida.
Só tome cuidado para não negligenciar o aprendizado da linguagem em si - já vi muita gente que segue um tutorial de Django, faz sua aplicação meio no copy e paste a partir dos exemplos do tutorial, e segue desenvolvendo sem ter muita idéia do que está fazendo.
Para aprender Python, uma das melhores pedidas é o tutorial disponível no próprio site da linguagem - http://python.org

Outros frameworks são menores, e permitem a troca de componentes - por exemplo, é mais fácil armazenar os dados num banco NoSQL se você estiver usando Flask (outro framework) do que usando Django - ali a camada de persistência de dados é completamente plugável.